# Select records by month and year between two dates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the table record_b. I want to select the records of an specific month and year between begin_date and end_date.

| id | begin_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-09-04 | 2022-10-03 |
| 3 | 2022-10-04 | 2022-10-31 |
| 4 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-12-03 |
| 5 | 2022-12-04 | 2023-01-03 |
| 6 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-02-03 |
| 7 | 2023-02-04 | null |

eg1:
Input: 2023-01
Output should be the record with id 5 and 6

eg2:
Input: 2022-12
Output should be the record with id 4 and 5

I have tried using between however there is a problem evaluating the months after the year.

```
and v_year BETWEEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PC.begin_date)
            AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PC.end_date)
        AND v_month BETWEEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PC.begin_date)
            AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PC.end_date)
```

Comment: what's the problem? since you mentioned there's a problem evaluating the months after the year

Answer (score 0):

A very basic dictate is *when you have a date store it as a date*.
This can be further extended to *when you need to process dates then process dates*.
Most of the nothing else will be needed - no conversion, extract, date_part, epoch - just dates.

The task here is to find those rows where a specified Year-Month (yyyy-mm) falls within the period begin and end dates from a table.
Realize that if any portion of the specified year-month falls within the period then the first day of that month (yyyy-mm-01) falls within that period.
You can use the [make_date()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function to get the first of the specified month. Then JOIN that result with `between` dates.

```
with input_val(yr_mon) as (values (:yyyymm)) --select * from input_val
   , tgt_date(dt) as 
     ( select 0make_date(substring(yr_mon,1,4)::integer
                       ,substring(yr_mon,6,2)::integer
                       ,01
                       )
         from input_val
     ) --select * from tgt_date;
select rb.*
  from tgt_date t 
  join record_b rb
    on t.dt between date_trunc('month',rb.begin_date) 
                and date_trunc('month',rb.end_date);
```

The above however does NOT handle well data point 7 with a `null` end date (nor would it handle a null start date). But should it?
If so a `null` value is often interpreted as *there in no ending date*, which basically says all dates on or after the start date are included.
You can handle the situation by converting the period to a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN), which will handle it without getting into null processing logic, then use the range containment operator.

```
with input_val(yr_mon) as (values (:yyyymm)) --select * from input_val
   , tgt_date(dt) as 
     ( select make_date(substring(yr_mon,1,4)::integer
                       ,substring(yr_mon,6,2)::integer
                       ,01
                       )
         from input_val
     ) --select * from tgt_date;
select rb.*
  from tgt_date t 
  join record_b rb
    on t.dt <@ daterange(date_trunc('month',rb.begin_date)::date 
                        ,date_trunc('month',rb.end_date)::date 
                        , '[]'
                        );
```

Finally, depending on how you you use the results, you can hide this whole thing within a SQL function, which can then be used in an SQL statement.

```
create or replace function periods_with_year_month(year_mm text) 
  returns setof record_b
 language sql
 as $$
     with tgt_date(dt) as  
          (select make_date(substring(year_mm,1,4)::integer
                           ,substring(year_mm,6,2)::integer
                           ,01
                           )
           )
     select rb.*
       from tgt_date t 
       join record_b rb
         on t.dt <@ daterange( date_trunc('month',rb.begin_date)::date 
                             , date_trunc('month',rb.end_date)::date 
                             , '[]'
                             );
$$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G-_UMNwc). Unfortunately ,**db<>fiddle** is non-interactive, so parameters of `yyyy-mm` are hard coded.

Comment: It seems I have connection issues at the moment and there is no demo. I will retry later.